# Nested factory girl with nested attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

There are 2 factories (using FactoryGirl):

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :owner do
    name                                'Some name'
    email                               'test@gmail.com'
    phone                               '89020000000'
    password                            '123456'
    password_confirmation '123456'
    role
  end

end
```

And roles:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :role do
    description 'Owner'
  end

  factory :superuser_role do
    description 'Superuser'
  end
end
```

I want to add a :superuser factory that has the same fields as :owner except role. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :owner do
    name                                'Some name'
    email                               'test@gmail.com'
    phone                               '89020000000'
    password                            '123456'
    password_confirmation '123456'
    role

    factory :superuser do
      association :role, factory: :superuser_role
    end
  end

end
```